# Groupby and Apply for Rank Percentile Calculation

Tags: python

I want to calculate percentile rank for 'Value'

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Group':['group1','group1','group1','group2','group2','group2'],
                 'Value':[30,40,10,40,60,70]})
```

It works all fine for the following:

```
df['Value'].apply(lambda x : (x>=df['Value']).sum()/df['Value'].notnull().sum()*100)
```

But I want to groupby 'Group'

```
df.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(lambda x : (x>=df['Value']).sum()/df['Value'].notnull().sum()*100)
```

It gave me a error:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

BTW, is there any function that I can use for this rank percentile calculation?

I know there is np.nanpercentile(df['Value'], 20) which can give 20% of the value, is there anything function that can do inverse of this?

Welcome if there is an alternative to calculate percentile rank.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339758/percentile-rank-in-pandas-in-groups ?

Comment: I don't understand what final values do you want to get for `group1` and `group2`

Comment: This gives me the percentile rank, basically it checks how many numbers are greater than it and divide by the count of total numbers. If you check 'df['Value'].apply(lambda x : (x>=df['Value']).sum()/df['Value'].notnull().sum()*100)', you will see that 70 has a value of 100, meaning it is the largest number while 10 is 16.77 as it is the smallest number.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to do this based on its group. 'df['Value'].apply(lambda x : (x>=df['Value']).sum()/df['Value'].notnull().sum()*100)' pools all numbers together and calculate  rank percentile.